# DLIB: ImportError: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7: file too short

Tags: python, linux, dlib

I have recently installed Dlib using pip. But when I am importing it it is giving the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7: file too short
```

In libcudnn.so.7 is nothing. Please help me in resolving this problem.

Comment: Which Linux, how did you install it, are you using a virt-env and how do you import Dlib?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Yes I using virtualenv, import dlib.

Comment: Have you installed dlib in that virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost all the solutions here and on the github issues related to the issue and none of them  seemed to work. Eventually, I tried to `cat` the contents of my libcudnn.so files and turns out they were empty. Downloaded them again, copied them to the right place again, and it all worked.